# Cache of ID2D1Brush not working as expected

Tags: c++, com, direct2d

Since it's very expensive to create gradient brushes in Direct2D, I thought it would be a good idea to have a cache of brushes and just update the brush. But the result is not the same if I create the brush every loop or if I take it from the cache, but I don't understand what is different. My only guess is that it doesn't recalculate the gradient color values even if I set the new start/stop point.

If I always creates the brush, it works as expected.
If I take the brush from the cache, the resulting colors are not correct.

Do you have any ideas what could be the problem with the cache?

UPDATE: It was just a simple copy/paste error with stat/end points that was the problem.

```
ID2D1RenderTarget* pRenderTarget = GetRenderTarget();
CComPtr<ID2D1LinearGradientBrush> gradientBrush;

// A cache for brushes
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, CComPtr<ID2D1LinearGradientBrush>> mapBrushCache;

// Draw all lines
for (int index = 0; index < iSize - 1; ++index)
{
    // Get the correct colors and positions for current line
    COLORREF cStart = vecColors[index];
    COLORREF cStop = vecColors[index + 1];
    D2D1_POINT_2F ptStart = vecPoints[index];
    D2D1_POINT_2F ptStop = vecPoints[index + 1];

    // See if we already has that brush in the cache
    uint64_t uiCol = (uint64_t)cStart << 32 | cStop;
    itBrush = mapBrushCache.find(uiCol);
    if (itBrush != mapBrushCache.end())
    {
       // Just update the gradient
       gradientBrush = itBrush->second;
       gradientBrush->SetStartPoint(ptStart);
       gradientBrush->SetStopPoint(ptStop);
    }
    else
    {
       // Create a new brush and save it in the cache
       D2Dutilities::CreateGradientBrush(cStart, cStop, ptStart, ptStop, pRenderTarget, &gradientBrush);
       mapBrushCache[uiCol] = gradientBrush;
    }

    // Draw the actual line
    pRenderTarget->DrawLine(ptStart, ptStop, gradientBrush, rPen.GetLineWidth(), pStrokeStyle);
}
```

Comment: Anything created on a render target instance (such as a brush) can only be used on that render target instance. Are you sure you don't have error on renderTarget.EndDraw() ?

Comment: Thanks, I will double check where EndDraw is called. But I would guess that would result in some exception thrown, not just a little incorrect gradiant in the the brush. (The colors are correct, but the gradient looks wrong)

Comment: Your cache must be per render target, not absolute. Also, you must check all HRESULT values, there's no exception thrown. You can also enable the D3D11 debug layer to get more information from VS's output window.

Comment: I clear the cache before the loop where all lines are drawn, so all brushes should use the same render target. I will take a look at HRESULT values.

Comment: I though that I just made a copy paste error to the example code here, but acutally I did set the StartPoint to the stop point. Now everything is working! :) Thanks for all your ideas!